# Auto version increment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a Asp.net project framework version 4.6.1  using visual studio 2017 .I want to implement version auto increment in my project  . I changed in assembly.cs as below but it gives me a compile error .

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.*")]
```

I tried to find a solution from the internet there are many using gulp bumb , but i couldn't find a project.json in source to implement that . I want to do this without adding   3rd party packages

Comment: only solution is vsts or using some third party.   Not to mention its probably time to jump to 2.1 since project.json is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

After a recent VS 2017 update most of my Framework class library projects have been throwing the same sort of error.
I'm not sure the implications of this "fix" yet but what has worked for me is changing the following line in the csproj file

```
<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
```

to

```
<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
```

I noticed that in my ASP.Net MVC Framework projects that value is not in the project file at all so maybe just removing it will get you by.

Alternatively you could put some make routine in place to increment the Assembly Version.